# `expect`-like behaviour in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a script (let's name it `parent.sh`) that calls some other scripts based on input parameters.

Finally, it calls the script `child.sh`.
`child.sh` requests user's input in case it find that some files already exists:

```
"Would you like to replace the configuration file with a new one? (Yes/No/Abort): "
```

Now, what I want to do it to simulate the keystroke of **"Y"/"y"** inside the `parent.sh` script in order to always overwrite the files.

I **cannot** use `expect`.

How can I do that?

Comment: How is child.sh getting the input? If simply reads from STDIN, then `echo y | child.sh` should do it. (If the question may occur multiple times, then `yes y | child.sh`.)

Comment: @manatwork that's really an answer. I was about to post it but that would then called a copy-paste. :)

Comment: May be an answer, unless parent.sh already passes input to child.sh, so child.sh reads user input from /dev/tty.

Comment: parent.sh call child.sh as follows:

`... bla bla ...
child.sh option`

Comment: @Peter: `man yes`, read it

Comment: It seems to do the trick. Someone must change the comment to answer

Answer (score 1):

While `yes | child.sh` as *manatwork* already commented is a valid solution, from a programmers point of view I would patch `child.sh` to be able to handle this usecase.

Like add an `--force` option to not prompt but always overwrite files.

But to answer the subject of your question and to get something more `expect`-like and not only fire `y` via a pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash

fifo=fifo

mkfifo ${fifo}

exec 3<> ${fifo}

expect="Would you like to replace the configuration file with a new one? (Yes/No/Abort): "
answer="y"

while IFS= read -d $'\0' -n 1 a ; do
    str+="${a}"

    if [ "${str}" = "${expect}" ] ; then
        echo "!!! found: ${str}"
        echo ">>> sending answer: ${answer}"
        echo "${answer}" >&3
        unset str
    fi

    if [ "$a" = $'\n' ] ; then
        echo -n "--- discarding input line: ${str}"
        unset str
    fi
done < <(./child.sh <${fifo})

rm ${fifo}
```

I just wrote that.. so it is not really failsafe or tested for solving specific problems.. 
So use at your own risk 8) Some line buffering problems may occur under some conditions..

But at least it worked in my test scenario..