# Automation of ssh change password on 1-st login (no expect)

Tags: ssh, scripting, password

My account was copied from 1 to a big number of hosts. On every host on 1-st login I get:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user dmitresso.
Changing password for dmitresso.
(current) UNIX password:
```

Trying to automate this proccess I'm writing script, where I've following progress in a part of changing password:

```
#! /bin/bash

username=dmitresso
hostname=aaa
pass=bbb
newpass=ccc

sshpass -p "${pass}" ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${username}@${hostname}
```

I've tried `echo -e "${pass}\n${newpass}\n${newpass}" | sshpass -p "${pass}" ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${username}@${hostname}`
but it gives my passwords as output before dialogue starts:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
bbb
ccc
ccc
Changing password for user dmitresso.
Changing password for dmitresso.
(current) UNIX password:
```

and another variations.

Many posts tell about similar situations, but there:

1. Using `passwd` [on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837674/changing-a-linux-password-via-script) or passing `passwd` with arguments through ssh where someone initiates password changes on his own;
2. [Also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66138/expect-like-behaviour-in-bash-script) without any ssh;
3. With [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) I can't use (it's not installed, I have no root)